# How to change the width of a HTML table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am declaring a table this way:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="module span12">
           <section class="module">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">

                echo "<tr><td style='color: white; background-color: black;'><strong>Overall inventory breakdown</strong></td>";
                echo "<td style='text-align: center; color: white; background-color: black;'><strong></strong></td>";
                echo "<td style='text-align: center; color: white; background-color: black;'><strong>Ist</strong></td>";
                echo "<td style='text-align: center; color: white; background-color: black;'><strong>Soll</strong></td></tr>";

                </table>    
          </section>
     </div>
</div>
```

Right now, the table is as wide as the entire page. But I want it to be smaller.

I already tried with several CSS variations, such as set `width` value on each `td`, but nothing works for me. Any help?

Comment: It is not as wide as the entire page — http://jsbin.com/vafuxi/1/edit?html,output — at least not with the code you've provided (which, incidentally, is invalid). Probably something is missing. You need to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you mean by invalid?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a Bootstrap question.

```
.table {
    /* width: 100%; */
    width: auto;
}
```

Get to know your browser's document inspection tool. It makes discovering the source of things like this trivial.

Comment: This did the trick! I tried all other options but nothing else worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the `width` on the `table` instead of `td`, i.e.

```
<table class="table" width="80%">
```

Or do it with CSS recommend, by default `<table>` has the ***shrink-to-fit*** feature, it is likely that was overridden somewhere in the stylesheet, perhaps from the CSS framework. Try to reset it:

```
.table { width: 80%; }
```

Preferably `.the-parent-class .table { width: 80%; }` so it won't affect the table style in other places on your website.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="module span12">
            <section class="module">
                <table width="500" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
                    echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td style='color: white; background-color: black;'><strong>Overall inventory breakdown</strong></td>"; echo "
                        <td style='text-align: center; color: white; background-color: black;'><strong></strong></td>"; echo "
                        <td style='text-align: center; color: white; background-color: black;'><strong>Ist</strong></td>"; echo "
                        <td style='text-align: center; color: white; background-color: black;'><strong>Soll</strong></td>
                    </tr>";
                </table>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Add width as attribute to table

Comment: Unable to understand. You should prove it by codes.

Comment: Sorry for typo. It is width. If you dont want to use CSS, above code is the way to limit table size

Comment: no no its not my question m just enjoying the coding :) aren't you think if we are not using php then we should remove the echo family???

Answer (score 0):

**Using you current HTML code, you could had a `width` value in your CSS as follows:**

```
.row { width: 80%; }
```